# Removing the thick blue boundary lines from the leaflet output map / Preventing the map to partly disappear when a pop-up appears

Tags: leaflet, qgis

I created a map of Africa that shows all of Africa's administrative divisions. The purpose of this map is to show its users in which country each of the African languages is spoken.

When I try to export it to a web map, it adds a thick blue line that represents the boundaries of these divisions. How can I remove the thick blue line?

[image]

Another problem this map has is that when I hover over any of the divisions, a pop up appears that contains info about that division. The popup causes the map to move lower in order to fit. How can I prevent it?

[image]

The expected result that I have in mind is that when the users hover over any of the administrative divisions a pop up appears which provides the name of the division and the language that is spoken in that division.

SO I have tried:

- Checking if there is anywhere in my files where I can set the "Autopan" into false
- Using leaflet-responsive-popup
- Using Openlayers instead of Leaflet

But none of them worked. Currently what I am doing is deleting some columns.

I would appreciate any help or idea that can help me with fixing the issue.

The version of the QGIS that I am using is 3.16.1 - Hannover and the version of QGIS2WEB is 3.16.0.

The HTML and .js generated by QGIS2WEB is below:

```js
var layer_Eth_Region_2013_Project_Merg_0 = new L.geoJson(json_Eth_Region_2013_Project_Merg_0, {
            attribution: '',
            interactive: true,
            dataVar: 'json_Eth_Region_2013_Project_Merg_0',
            layerName: 'layer_Eth_Region_2013_Project_Merg_0',
            pane: 'pane_Eth_Region_2013_Project_Merg_0',
            onEachFeature: pop_Eth_Region_2013_Project_Merg_0,
            style: style_Eth_Region_2013_Project_Merg_0_0,
        });
        bounds_group.addLayer(layer_Eth_Region_2013_Project_Merg_0);
        map.addLayer(layer_Eth_Region_2013_Project_Merg_0);
        var osmGeocoder = new L.Control.Geocoder({
            collapsed: true,
            position: 'topleft',
            text: 'Search',
            title: 'Testing'
        }).addTo(map);
```

```js
autoPanSpeed,o=this._marker.options.autoPanPadding,s=Li(i._icon),r=e.getPixelBounds(),a=e.getPixelOrigin(),h=R(r.min._subtract(a).add(o),r.max._subtract(a).subtract(o));if(!h.contains(s)){var u=I((Math.max(h.max.x,s.x)-h.max.x)/(r.max.x-h.max.x)-(Math.min(h.min.x,s.x)-h.min.x)/(r.min.x-h.min.x),(Math.max(h.max.y,s.y)-h.max.y)/(r.max.y-h.max.y)-(Math.min

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```js
(h.min.y,s.y)-h.min.y)/(r.min.y-h.min.y)).multiplyBy(n);e.panBy(u,{animate:!1}),this._draggable._newPos._add(u),this._draggable._startPos._add(u),Pi(i._icon,this._draggable._newPos),this._onDrag(t),this._panRequest=M(this._adjustPan.bind(this,t))}},_onDragStart:function(){this._oldLatLng=this._marker.getLatLng(),this._marker.closePopup().fire("movestart").fire("dragstart")},_onPreDrag:function(t){this._marker.options.autoPan&&(C(this._panRequest),this._panRequest=M(this._adjustPan.bind(this,t)))},_onDrag:function(t){var i=this._marker,e=i._shadow,n=Li(i._icon),o=i._map.layerPointToLatLng(n);e&&Pi(e,n),i._latlng=o,t.latlng=o,t.oldLatLng=this._oldLatLng,i.fire("move",t).fire("drag",t)},_onDragEnd:function(t){C(this._panRequest),delete this._oldLatLng,this._marker.fire("moveend").fire("dragend",t)}}),Oe=Se.extend({options:{icon:new Ae,interactive:!0,keyboard:!0,title:"",alt:"",zIndexOffset:0,opacity:1,riseOnHover:!1,riseOffset:250,pane:"markerPane",shadowPane:"shadowPane",bubblingMouseEvents:!1,draggable:!1,autoPan:!1,autoPanPadding:[50,50],autoPanSpeed:10},initialize:function(t,i){p(this,i),this._latlng=W(t)},onAdd:function(t){this._zoomAnimated=this._zoomAnimated&&t.options.markerZoomAnimation,this._zoomAnimated&&t.on("zoomanim",this._animateZoom,this),this._initIcon(),this.update()},onRemove:function(t){this.dragging&&this.dragging.enabled()&&(this.options.draggable=!0,this.dragging.removeHooks()),delete this.dragging,this._zoomAnimated&&t.off("zoomanim",this._animateZoom,this),this._removeIcon(),this._removeShadow()},getEvents:function(){return{zoom:this.update,viewreset:this.update}},getLatLng:function(){return this._latlng},setLatLng:function(t){var i=this._latlng;return this._latlng=W(t),this.update(),this.fire("move",{oldLatLng:i,latlng:this._latlng})},setZIndexOffset:function(t){return this.options.zIndexOffset=t,this.update()},getIcon:function(){return this.options.icon},setIcon:function(t){return this.options.icon=t,this._map&&(this._initIcon(),this.update()),this._popup&&this.bindPopup(this._popup,this._popup.options),this},getElement:function(){return this._icon},update:function(){if(this._icon&&this._map){var t=this._map.latLngToLayerPoint(this._latlng).round();this._setPos(t)}return this},_initIcon:function(){var t=this.options,i="leaflet-zoom-"+(this._zoomAnimated?"animated":"hide"),e=t.icon.createIcon(this._icon),n=!1;e!==this._icon&&(this._icon&&this._removeIcon(),n=!0,t.title&&(e.title=t.title),"IMG"===e.tagName&&(e.alt=t.alt||"")),mi(e,i),t.keyboard&&(e.tabIndex="0"),this._icon=e,t.riseOnHover&&this.on({mouseover:this._bringToFront,mouseout:this._resetZIndex});var o=t.icon.createShadow(this._shadow),s=!1;o!==this._shadow&&(this._removeShadow(),s=!0),o&&(mi(o,i),o.alt=""),this._shadow=o,t.opacity<1&&this._updateOpacity(),n&&this.getPane().appendChild(this._icon),this._initInteraction(),o&&s&&this.getPane(t.shadowPane).appendChild(this._shadow)},_removeIcon:function(){this.options.riseOnHover&&this.off({mouseover:this._bringToFront,mouseout:this._resetZIndex}),li(this._icon),this.removeInteractiveTarget(this._icon),this._icon=null},_removeShadow:function(){this._shadow&&li(this._shadow),this._shadow=null},_setPos:function(t){this._icon&&Pi(this._icon,t),this._shadow&&Pi(this._shadow,t),this._zIndex=t.y+this.options.zIndexOffset,this._resetZIndex()},_updateZIndex:function(t){this._icon&&(this._icon.style.zIndex=this._zIndex+t)},_animateZoom:function(t){var i=this._map._latLngToNewLayerPoint(this._latlng,t.zoom,t.center).round();this._setPos(i)},_initInteraction:function(){if(this.options.interactive&&(mi(this._icon,"leaflet-interactive"),this.addInteractiveTarget(this._icon),Ie)){var t=this.options.draggable;this.dragging&&(t=this.dragging.enabled(),this.dragging.disable()),this.dragging=new Ie(this),t&&this.dragging.enable()}},setOpacity:function(t){return this.options.opacity=t,this._map&&this._updateOpacity(),this},_updateOpacity:function(){var t=this.options.opacity;this._icon&&yi(this._icon,t),this._shadow&&yi(this._shadow,t)},_bringToFront:function(){this._updateZIndex(this.options.riseOffset)},_resetZIndex:function(){this._updateZIndex(0)},_getPopupAnchor:function(){return this.options.icon.options.popupAnchor},_getTooltipAnchor:function(){return this.options.icon.options.tooltipAnchor}});var Re=Se.extend({options:{stroke:!0,color:"#3388ff",weight:3,opacity:1,lineCap:"round",lineJoin:"round",dashArray:null,dashOffset:null,fill:!1,fillColor:null,fillOpacity:.2,fillRule:"evenodd",interactive:!0,bubblingMouseEvents:!0},beforeAdd:function(t){this._renderer=t.getRenderer(this)},onAdd:function(){this._renderer._initPath(this),this._reset(),this._renderer._addPath(this)},onRemove:function(){this._renderer._removePath(this)},redraw:function(){return this._map&&this._renderer._updatePath(this),this},setStyle:function(t){return p(this,t),this._renderer&&(this._renderer._updateStyle(this),this.options.stroke&&t&&t.hasOwnProperty("weight")&&this._updateBounds()),this},bringToFront:function(){return this._renderer&&this._renderer._bringToFront(this),this},bringToBack:function(){return this._renderer&&this._renderer._bringToBack(this),this},getElement:function(){return this._path},_reset:function(){this._project(),this._update()},_clickTolerance:function(){return(this.options.stroke?this.options.weight/2:0)+this._renderer.options.tolerance}}),Ne=Re.extend({options:{fill:!0,radius:10},initialize:function(t,i){p(this,i),this._latlng=W(t),this._radius=this.options.radius},setLatLng:function(t){var i=this._latlng;return this._latlng=W(t),this.redraw(),this.fire("move",{oldLatLng:i,latlng:this._latlng})},getLatLng:function(){return this._latlng},setRadius:function(t){return this.options.radius=this._radius=t,this.redraw()},getRadius:function(){return this._radius},setStyle:function(t){var i=t&&t.radius||this._radius;return Re.prototype.setStyle.call(this,t),this.setRadius(i),this},_project:function(){this._point=this._map.latLngToLayerPoint(this._latlng),this._updateBounds()},_updateBounds:function(){var t=this._radius,i=this._radiusY||t,e=this._clickTolerance(),n=[t+e,i+e];this._pxBounds=new O(this._point.subtract(n),this._point.add(n))},_update:function(){this._map&&this._updatePath()},_updatePath:function(){this._renderer._updateCircle(this)},_empty:function(){return this._radius&&!this._renderer._bounds.intersects(this._pxBounds)},_containsPoint:function(t){return t.distanceTo(this._point)<=this._radius+this._clickTolerance()}});var De=Ne.extend({initialize:function(t,i,e){if("number"==typeof i&&(i=h({},e,{radius:i})),p(this,i),this._latlng=W(t),isNaN(this.options.radius))throw new Error("Circle radius cannot be NaN");this._mRadius=this.options.radius},setRadius:function(t){return this._mRadius=t,this.redraw()},getRadius:function(){return this._mRadius},getBounds:function(){var t=[this._radius,this._radiusY||this._radius];return new N(this._map.layerPointToLatLng(this._point.subtract(t)),this._map.layerPointToLatLng(this._point.add(t)))},setStyle:Re.prototype.setStyle,_project:function(){var t=this._latlng.lng,i=this._latlng.lat,e=this._map,n=e.options.crs;if(n.distance===U.distance){var o=Math.PI/180,s=this._mRadius/U.R/o,r=e.project([i+s,t]),a=e.project([i-s,t]),h=r.add(a).divideBy(2),u=e.unproject(h).lat,l=Math.acos((Math.cos(s*o)-Math.sin(i*o)*Math.sin(u*o))/(Math.cos(i*o)*Math.cos(u*o)))/o;!isNaN(l)&&0!==l||(l=s/Math.cos(Math.PI/180*i)),this._point=h.subtract(e.getPixelOrigin()),this._radius=isNaN(l)?0:h.x-e.project([u,t-l]).x,this._radiusY=h.y-r.y}else{var c=n.unproject(n.project(this._latlng).subtract([this._mRadius,0]));this._point=e.latLngToLayerPoint(this._latlng),this._radius=this._point.x-e.latLngToLayerPoint(c).x}this._updateBounds()}});var je=Re.extend({options:{smoothFactor:1,noClip:!1},initialize:function(t,i){p(this,i),this._setLatLngs(t)},getLatLngs:function(){return this._latlngs},setLatLngs:function(t){return this._setLatLngs(t),this.redraw()},isEmpty:function(){return!this._latlngs.length},closestLayerPoint:function(t){for(var i,e,n=1/0,o=null,s=ge,r=0,a=this._parts.length;r<a;r++)for(var h=this._parts[r],u=1,l=h.length;u<l;u++){var c=s(t,i=h[u-1],e=h[u],!0);c<n&&(n=c,o=s(t,i,e))}return o&&(o.distance=Math.sqrt(n)),o},getCenter:function(){if(!this._map)throw new Error("Must add layer to map before using getCenter()");var t,i,e,n,o,s,r,a=this._rings[0],h=a.length;if(!h)return null;for(i=t=0;t<h-1;t++)i+=a[t].distanceTo(a[t+1])/2;if(0===i)return this._map.layerPointToLatLng(a[0]);for(n=t=0;t<h-1;t++)if(o=a[t],s=a[t+1],i<(n+=e=o.distanceTo(s)))return r=(n-i)/e,this._map.layerPointToLatLng([s.x-r*(s.x-o.x),s.y-r*(s.y-o.y)])},getBounds:function(){return this._bounds},addLatLng:function(t,i){return i=i||this._defaultShape(),t=W(t),i.push(t),this._bounds.extend(t),this.redraw()},_setLatLngs:function(t){this._bounds=new N,this._latlngs=this._convertLatLngs(t)},_defaultShape:function(){return ve(this._latlngs)?this._latlngs:this._latlngs[0]},_convertLatLngs:function(t){for(var i=[],e=ve(t),n=0,o=t.length;n<o;n++)e?(i[n]=W(t[n]),this._bounds.extend(i[n])):i[n]=this._convertLatLngs(t[n]);return i},_project:function(){var t=new O;this._rings=[],this._projectLatlngs(this._latlngs,this._rings,t),this._bounds.isValid()&&t.isValid()&&(this._rawPxBounds=t,this._updateBounds())},_updateBounds:function(){var t=this._clickTolerance(),i=new B(t,t);this._pxBounds=new O([this._rawPxBounds.min.subtract(i),this._rawPxBounds.max.add(i)])},_projectLatlngs:function(t,i,e){var n,o,s=t[0]instanceof j,r=t.length;if(s){for(o=[],n=0;n<r;n++)o[n]=this._map.latLngToLayerPoint(t[n]),e.extend(o[n]);i.push(o)}else for(n=0;n<r;n++)this._projectLatlngs(t[n],i,e)},_clipPoints:function(){var t=this._renderer._bounds;if(this._parts=[],this._pxBounds&&this._pxBounds.intersects(t))if(this.options.noClip)this._parts=this._rings;else{var i,e,n,o,s,r,a,h=this._parts;for(n=i=0,o=this._rings.length;i<o;i++)for(e=0,s=(a=this._rings[i]).length;e<s-1;e++)(r=pe(a[e],a[e+1],t,e,!0))&&(h[n]=h[n]||[],h[n].push(r[0]),r[1]===a[e+1]&&e!==s-2||(h[n].push(r[1]),n++))}},_simplifyPoints:function(){for(var t=this._parts,i=this.options.smoothFactor,e=0,n=t.length;e<n;e++)t[e]=_e(t[e],i)},_update:function(){this._map&&(this._clipPoints(),this._simplifyPoints(),this._updatePath())},_updatePath:function(){this._renderer._updatePoly(this)},_containsPoint:function(t,i){var e,n,o,s,r,a,h=this._clickTolerance();if(!this._pxBounds||!this._pxBounds.contains(t))return!1;for(e=0,s=this._parts.length;e<s;e++)for(n=0,o=(r=(a=this._parts[e]).length)-1;n<r;o=n++)if((i||0!==n)&&de(t,a[o],a[n])<=h)return!0;return!1}});je._flat=ye;var We=je.extend({options:{fill:!0},isEmpty:function(){return!this._latlngs.length||!this._latlngs[0].length},getCenter:function(){if(!this._map)throw new Error("Must add layer to map before using getCenter()");var t,i,e,n,o,s,r,a,h,u=this._rings[0],l=u.length;if(!l)return null;for(s=r=a=0,t=0,i=l-1;t<l;i=t++)e=u[t],n=u[i],o=e.y*n.x-n.y*e.x,r+=(e.x+n.x)*o,a+=(e.y+n.y)*o,s+=3*o;return h=0===s?u[0]:[r/s,a/s],this._map.layerPointToLatLng(h)},_convertLatLngs:function(t){var i=je.prototype._convertLatLngs.call(this,t),e=i.length;return 2<=e&&i[0]instanceof j&&i[0].equals(i[e-1])&&i.pop(),i},_setLatLngs:function(t){je.prototype._setLatLngs.call(this,t),ve(this._latlngs)&&(this._latlngs=[this._latlngs])},_defaultShape:function(){return ve(this._latlngs[0])?this._latlngs[0]:this._latlngs[0][0]},_clipPoints:function(){var t=this._renderer._bounds,i=this.options.weight,e=new B(i,i);if(t=new O(t.min.subtract(e),t.max.add(e)),this._parts=[],this._pxBounds&&this._pxBounds.intersects(t))if(this.options.noClip)this._parts=this._rings;else for(var n,o=0,s=this._rings.length;o<s;o++)(n=we(this._rings[o],t,!0)).length&&this._parts.push(n)},_updatePath:function(){this._renderer._updatePoly(this,!0)},_containsPoint:function(t){var i,e,n,o,s,r,a,h,u=!1;if(!this._pxBounds||!this._pxBounds.contains(t))return!1;for(o=0,a=this._parts.length;o<a;o++)for(s=0,r=(h=(i=this._parts[o]).length)-1;s<h;r=s++)e=i[s],n=i[r],e.y>t.y!=n.y>t.y&&t.x<(n.x-e.x)*(t.y-e.y)/(n.y-e.y)+e.x&&(u=!u);return u||je.prototype._containsPoint.call(this,t,!0)}});var He=ke.extend({initialize:function(t,i){p(this,i),this._layers={},t&&this.addData(t)},addData:function(t){var i,e,n,o=v(t)?t:t.features;if(o){for(i=0,e=o.length;i<e;i++)((n=o[i]).geometries||n.geometry||n.features||n.coordinates)&&this.addData(n);return this}var s=this.options;if(s.filter&&!s.filter(t))return this;var r=Fe(t,s);return r?(r.feature=Xe(t),r.defaultOptions=r.options,this.resetStyle(r),s.onEachFeature&&s.onEachFeature(t,r),this.addLayer(r)):this},resetStyle:function(t){return void 0===t?this.eachLayer(this.resetStyle,this):(t.options=h({},t.defaultOptions),this._setLayerStyle(t,this.options.style),this)},setStyle:function(i){return this.eachLayer(function(t){this._setLayerStyle(t,i)},this)},_setLayerStyle:function(t,i){t.setStyle&&("function"==typeof i&&(i=i(t.feature)),t.setStyle(i))}});function Fe(t,i){var e,n,o,s,r="Feature"===t.type?t.geometry:t,a=r?r.coordinates:null,h=[],u=i&&i.pointToLayer,l=i&&i.coordsToLatLng||Ve;if(!a&&!r)return null;switch(r.type){case"Point":return Ue(u,t,e=l(a),i);case"MultiPoint":for(o=0,s=a.length;o<s;o++)e=l(a[o]),h.push(Ue(u,t,e,i));return new ke(h);case"LineString":case"MultiLineString":return n=qe(a,"LineString"===r.type?0:1,l),new je(n,i);case"Polygon":case"MultiPolygon":return n=qe(a,"Polygon"===r.type?1:2,l),new We(n,i);case"GeometryCollection":for(o=0,s=r.geometries.length;o<s;o++){var c=Fe({geometry:r.geometries[o],type:"Feature",properties:t.properties},i);c&&h.push(c)}return new ke(h);default:throw new Error("Invalid GeoJSON object.")}}function Ue(t,i,e,n){return t?t(i,e):new Oe(e,n&&n.markersInheritOptions&&n)}function Ve(t){return new j(t[1],t[0],t[2])}function qe(t,i,e){for(var n,o=[],s=0,r=t.length;s<r;s++)n=i?qe(t[s],i-1,e):(e||Ve)(t[s]),o.push(n);return o}function Ge(t,i){return i="number"==typeof i?i:6,void 0!==t.alt?[c(t.lng,i),c(t.lat,i),c(t.alt,i)]:[c(t.lng,i),c(t.lat,i)]}function Ke(t,i,e,n){for(var o=[],s=0,r=t.length;s<r;s++)o.push(i?Ke(t[s],i-1,e,n):Ge(t[s],n));return!i&&e&&o.push(o[0]),o}function Ye(t,i){return t.feature?h({},t.feature,{geometry:i}):Xe(i)}function Xe(t){return"Feature"===t.type||"FeatureCollection"===t.type?t:{type:"Feature",properties:{},geometry:t}}var Je={toGeoJSON:function(t){return Ye(this,{type:"Point",coordinates:Ge(this.getLatLng(),t)})}};function $e(t,i){return new He(t,i)}Oe.include(Je),De.include(Je),Ne.include(Je),je.include({toGeoJSON:function(t){var i=!ve(this._latlngs);return Ye(this,{type:(i?"Multi":"")+"LineString",coordinates:Ke(this._latlngs,i?1:0,!1,t)})}}),We.include({toGeoJSON:function(t){var i=!ve(this._latlngs),e=i&&!ve(this._latlngs[0]),n=Ke(this._latlngs,e?2:i?1:0,!0,t);return i||(n=[n]),Ye(this,{type:(e?"Multi":"")+"Polygon",coordinates:n})}}),Ze.include({toMultiPoint:function(i){var e=[];return this.eachLayer(function(t){e.push(t.toGeoJSON(i).geometry.coordinates)}),Ye(this,{type:"MultiPoint",coordinates:e})},toGeoJSON:function(n){var t=this.feature&&this.feature.geometry&&this.feature.geometry.type;if("MultiPoint"===t)return this.toMultiPoint(n);var o="GeometryCollection"===t,s=[];return this.eachLayer(function(t){if(t.toGeoJSON){var i=t.toGeoJSON(n);if(o)s.push(i.geometry);else{var e=Xe(i);"FeatureCollection"===e.type?s.push.apply(s,e.features):s.push(e)}}}),o?Ye(this,{geometries:s,type:"GeometryCollection"}):{type:"FeatureCollection",features:s}}});var Qe=$e,tn=Se.extend({options:{opacity:1,alt:"",interactive:!1,crossOrigin:!1,errorOverlayUrl:"",zIndex:1,className:""},initialize:function(t,i,e){this._url=t,this._bounds=D(i),p(this,e)},onAdd:function(){this._image||(this._initImage(),this.options.opacity<1&&this._updateOpacity()),this.options.interactive&&(mi(this._image,"leaflet-interactive"),this.addInteractiveTarget(this._image)),this.getPane().appendChild(this._image),this._reset()},onRemove:function(){li(this._image),this.options.interactive&&this.removeInteractiveTarget(this._image)},setOpacity:function(t){return this.options.opacity=t,this._image&&this._updateOpacity(),this},setStyle:function(t){return t.opacity&&this.setOpacity(t.opacity),this},bringToFront:function(){return this._map&&_i(this._image),this},bringToBack:function(){return this._map&&di(this._image),this},setUrl:function(t){return this._url=t,this._image&&(this._image.src=t),this},setBounds:function(t){return this._bounds=D(t),this._map&&this._reset(),this},getEvents:function(){var t={zoom:this._reset,viewreset:this._reset};return this._zoomAnimated&&(t.zoomanim=this._animateZoom),t},setZIndex:function(t){return this.options.zIndex=t,this._updateZIndex(),this},getBounds:function(){return this._bounds},getElement:function(){return this._image},_initImage:function(){var t="IMG"===this._url.tagName,i=this._image=t?this._url:ui("img");mi(i,"leaflet-image-layer"),this._zoomAnimated&&mi(i,"leaflet-zoom-animated"),this.options.className&&mi(i,this.options.className),i.onselectstart=l,i.onmousemove=l,i.onload=a(this.fire,this,"load"),i.onerror=a(this._overlayOnError,this,"error"),!this.options.crossOrigin&&""!==this.options.crossOrigin||(i.crossOrigin=!0===this.options.crossOrigin?"":this.options.crossOrigin),this.options.zIndex&&this._updateZIndex(),t?this._url=i.src:(i.src=this._url,i.alt=this.options.alt)},_animateZoom:function(t){var i=this._map.getZoomScale(t.zoom),e=this._map._latLngBoundsToNewLayerBounds(this._bounds,t.zoom,t.center).min;wi(this._image,e,i)},_reset:function(){var t=this._image,i=new O(this._map.latLngToLayerPoint(this._bounds.getNorthWest()),this._map.latLngToLayerPoint(this._bounds.getSouthEast())),e=i.getSize();Pi(t,i.min),t.style.width=e.x+"px",t.style.height=e.y+"px"},_updateOpacity:function(){yi(this._image,this.options.opacity)},_updateZIndex:function(){this._image&&void 0!==this.options.zIndex&&null!==this.options.zIndex&&(this._image.style.zIndex=this.options.zIndex)},_overlayOnError:function(){this.fire("error");var t=this.options.errorOverlayUrl;t&&this._url!==t&&(this._url=t,this._image.src=t)}}),en=tn.extend({options:{autoplay:!0,loop:!0,keepAspectRatio:!0},_initImage:function(){var t="VIDEO"===this._url.tagName,i=this._image=t?this._url:ui("video");if(mi(i,"leaflet-image-layer"),this._zoomAnimated&&mi(i,"leaflet-zoom-animated"),this.options.className&&mi(i,this.options.className),i.onselectstart=l,i.onmousemove=l,i.onloadeddata=a(this.fire,this,"load"),t){for(var e=i.getElementsByTagName("source"),n=[],o=0;o<e.length;o++)n.push(e[o].src);this._url=0<e.length?n:[i.src]}else{v(this._url)||(this._url=[this._url]),!this.options.keepAspectRatio&&i.style.hasOwnProperty("objectFit")&&(i.style.objectFit="fill"),i.autoplay=!!this.options.autoplay,i.loop=!!this.options.loop;for(var s=0;s<this._url.length;s++){var r=ui("source");r.src=this._url[s],i.appendChild(r)}}}});var nn=tn.extend({_initImage:function(){var t=this._image=this._url;mi(t,"leaflet-image-layer"),this._zoomAnimated&&mi(t,"leaflet-zoom-animated"),this.options.className&&mi(t,this.options.className),t.onselectstart=l,t.onmousemove=l}});var on=Se.extend({options:{offset:[0,7],className:"",pane:"popupPane"},initialize:function(t,i){p(this,t),this._source=i},onAdd:function(t){this._zoomAnimated=t._zoomAnimated,this._container||this._initLayout(),t._fadeAnimated&&yi(this._container,0),clearTimeout(this._removeTimeout),this.getPane().appendChild(this._container),this.update(),t._fadeAnimated&&yi(this._container,1),this.bringToFront()},onRemove:function(t){t._fadeAnimated?(yi(this._container,0),this._removeTimeout=setTimeout(a(li,void 0,this._container),200)):li(this._container)},getLatLng:function(){return this._latlng},setLatLng:function(t){return this._latlng=W(t),this._map&&(this._updatePosition(),this._adjustPan()),this},getContent:function(){return this._content},setContent:function(t){return this._content=t,this.update(),this},getElement:function(){return this._container},update:function(){this._map&&(this._container.style.visibility="hidden",this._updateContent(),this._updateLayout(),this._updatePosition(),this._container.style.visibility="",this._adjustPan())},getEvents:function(){var t={zoom:this._updatePosition,viewreset:this._updatePosition};return this._zoomAnimated&&(t.zoomanim=this._animateZoom),t},isOpen:function(){return!!this._map&&this._map.hasLayer(this)},bringToFront:function(){return this._map&&_i(this._container),this},bringToBack:function(){return this._map&&di(this._container),this},_prepareOpen:function(t,i,e){if(i instanceof Se||(e=i,i=t),i instanceof ke)for(var n in t._layers){i=t._layers[n];break}if(!e)if(i.getCenter)e=i.getCenter();else{if(!i.getLatLng)throw new Error("Unable to get source layer LatLng.");e=i.getLatLng()}return this._source=i,this.update(),e},_updateContent:function(){if(this._content){var t=this._contentNode,i="function"==typeof this._content?this._content(this._source||this):this._content;if("string"==typeof i)t.innerHTML=i;else{for(;t.hasChildNodes();)t.removeChild(t.firstChild);t.appendChild(i)}this.fire("contentupdate")}},_updatePosition:function(){if(this._map){var t=this._map.latLngToLayerPoint(this._latlng),i=I(this.options.offset),e=this._getAnchor();this._zoomAnimated?Pi(this._container,t.add(e)):i=i.add(t).add(e);var n=this._containerBottom=-i.y,o=this._containerLeft=-Math.round(this._containerWidth/2)+i.x;this._container.style.bottom=n+"px",this._container.style.left=o+"px"}},_getAnchor:function(){return[0,0]}}),sn=on.extend({options:{maxWidth:300,minWidth:50,maxHeight:null,autoPan:!0,autoPanPaddingTopLeft:null,autoPanPaddingBottomRight:null,autoPanPadding:[5,5],keepInView:!1,closeButton:!0,autoClose:!0,closeOnEscapeKey:!0,className:""},openOn:function(t){return t.openPopup(this),this},onAdd:function(t){on.prototype.onAdd.call(this,t),t.fire("popupopen",{popup:this}),this._source&&(this._source.fire("popupopen",{popup:this},!0),this._source instanceof Re||this._source.on("preclick",Ri))},onRemove:function(t){on.prototype.onRemove.call(this,t),t.fire("popupclose",{popup:this}),this._source&&(this._source.fire("popupclose",{popup:this},!0),this._source instanceof Re||this._source.off("preclick",Ri))},getEvents:function(){var t=on.prototype.getEvents.call(this);return(void 0!==this.options.closeOnClick?this.options.closeOnClick:this._map.options.closePopupOnClick)&&(t.preclick=this._close),this.options.keepInView&&(t.moveend=this._adjustPan),t},_close:function(){this._map&&this._map.closePopup(this)},_initLayout:function(){var t="leaflet-popup",i=this._container=ui("div",t+" "+(this.options.className||"")+" leaflet-zoom-animated"),e=this._wrapper=ui("div",t+"-content-wrapper",i);if(this._contentNode=ui("div",t+"-content",e),Di(e),Ni(this._contentNode),ki(e,"contextmenu",Ri),this._tipContainer=ui("div",t+"-tip-container",i),this._tip=ui("div",t+"-tip",this._tipContainer),this.options.closeButton){var n=this._closeButton=ui("a",t+"-close-button",i);n.href="#close",n.innerHTML="&#215;",ki(n,"click",this._onCloseButtonClick,this)}},_updateLayout:function(){var t=this._contentNode,i=t.style;i.width="",i.whiteSpace="nowrap";var e=t.offsetWidth;e=Math.min(e,this.options.maxWidth),e=Math.max(e,this.options.minWidth),i.width=e+1+"px",i.whiteSpace="",i.height="";var n=t.offsetHeight,o=this.options.maxHeight,s="leaflet-popup-scrolled";o&&o<n?(i.height=o+"px",mi(t,s)):fi(t,s),this._containerWidth=this._container.offsetWidth},_animateZoom:function(t){var i=this._map._latLngToNewLayerPoint(this._latlng,t.zoom,t.center),e=this._getAnchor();Pi(this._container,i.add(e))},_adjustPan:function(){if(this.options.autoPan){this._map._panAnim&&this._map._panAnim.stop();var t=this._map,i=parseInt(hi(this._container,"marginBottom"),10)||0,e=this._container.offsetHeight+i,n=this._containerWidth,o=new B(this._containerLeft,-e-this._containerBottom);o._add(Li(this._container));var s=t.layerPointToContainerPoint(o),r=I(this.options.autoPanPadding),a=I(this.options.autoPanPaddingTopLeft||r),h=I(this.options.autoPanPaddingBottomRight||r),u=t.getSize(),l=0,c=0;s.x+n+h.x>u.x&&(l=s.x+n-u.x+h.x),s.x-l-a.x<0&&(l=s.x-a.x),s.y+e+h.y>u.y&&(c=s.y+e-u.y+h.y),s.y-c-a.y<0&&(c=s.y-a.y),(l||c)&&t.fire("autopanstart")
```

```js
function pop_Eth_Region_2013_Project_Merg_0(feature, layer) {
            layer.on({
                mouseout: function(e) {
                    for (i in e.target._eventParents) {
                        e.target._eventParents[i].resetStyle(e.target);
                    }
                    if (typeof layer.closePopup == 'function') {
                        layer.closePopup();
                    } else {
                        layer.eachLayer(function(feature){
                            feature.closePopup()
                        });
                    }
                },
                mouseover: highlightFeature,
            });
```

```js
function style_Eth_Region_2013_Project_Merg_0_0(feature) {
            switch(String(feature.properties['lang2'])) {
                case 'Acholi':
                    return {
                pane: 'pane_Eth_Region_2013_Project_Merg_0',
                stroke: false,
                fill: true,
                fillOpacity: 1,
                fillColor: 'rgba(66,208,14,1.0)',
                interactive: true,
            }
```

```js
var highlightLayer;
        function highlightFeature(e) {
            highlightLayer = e.target;

            if (e.target.feature.geometry.type === 'LineString') {
              highlightLayer.setStyle({
                color: '#ffff00',
              });
            } else {
              highlightLayer.setStyle({
                fillColor: '#ffff00',
                fillOpacity: 1
              });
            }
            highlightLayer.openPopup();
        }
```

Comment: So - are you using `qgis2web`?

Comment: Yes, I am using QGIS2Web

Comment: Please edit your question to include the versions of qgis and qgis2web that you're using; also consider adding the HTML+JS code generated by qgis2web as well.

Comment: Hi Ivan, sorry for the delay. I made the changes that you asked for. Thank you for the help again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implemantaion of the following depends how you import your data, but in gernal to disable the border you have to set [stroke](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#polygon-stroke) to false:

```
polygon.setStyle({stroke: false});
```

But I think you import your data into a `L.GeoJSON` group. Then you have to add `stroke: false` to your [style function](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#geojson)

---

To prevent that the map is moving when the popup is displayed you have to set [autoPan](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#popup-autopan) to `false`.

---

**Update**

Remove border:

```
function style_Eth_Region_2013_Project_Merg_0_0(feature) {
    switch(String(feature.properties['lang2'])) {
       case 'Acholi':
           return {
                pane: 'pane_Eth_Region_2013_Project_Merg_0',
                stroke: false,
                fill: true,
                fillOpacity: 1,
                fillColor: 'rgba(66,208,14,1.0)',
                interactive: true,
            }
    }
}
```

There have to be a `bindPopup()` in your code and there you have to add the options `autoPan` `layer.bindPopup(html,{autoPan: false})`

Else you can loop through all layers and add the option:

```
layer_Eth_Region_2013_Project_Merg_0.eachLayer((layer)=>{
  if(layer._popup){
    layer._popup.options.autoPan = false;
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you. As for autoPan, there are two files that contain autoPan: one is js/leaflet.js and the other one is jd/leaflet.js.map. I am not sure in which file I should make the change. Below are the codes:

Comment: @KavehEkbia I updated my answer. If you need more help I need the code for the function `pop_Eth_Region_2013_Project_Merg_0` and `style_Eth_Region_2013_Project_Merg_0_0`

Comment: Thank you for the help. I added the code for the two functions (top). I am working on it as well. I just want to make sure that I am doing it correctly.

Comment: please share also the function `highlightFeature`

Comment: It is now shared

Comment: I updated the answer. You have implemented the style correct but I added it to my answer too. Also in your code must be a call `bindPopup` and there you can set the popup options, else you can loop through all layers. Please don't forgett to check the answer and upvote it

Comment: Again, thank you so much. So where exactly is "border:" located at? Is it within one of the functions that shared? There is one another issue and I was wondering if you can give me any tips or hints. When I try to open the map (index.html) in Firefox, it loads slowly. As for bindPopup, where exactly in pop_Eth_Region_2013_Project_Merg_0 function it goes? I appreciate all your wonderful help and sorry for taking your valuable time. I will fo sure upvote it.

Comment: "border" is `stroke: false`. Does it load in Chrome better? The `bindPopup` should be already anywhere in your code but you haven't posted it. If there is nowhere a `bindPopup` you can use the loop for each layer that I posted. It would be nice if you can create live demo, maybe on jsfiddle.net

Comment: I feel like it is loading better in Chrome. I will definitely create a live demo and inform you.   I also added an screen shot showing the list of bindPopups in my code. Can you please check it and see if it is any of them? Thank you

Comment: It does not allow me to embed a picture. Can I send it to you somehow else (ex. email)?

Comment: Hi Florian, I commented out all "border" (stroke: false) in the index.html page, however the lines still show up. Have I done something wrong?